# How do I write parallel code in R to index over objects simultaneously?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

So I have two large lists of strings, and I want to check each string in the list for five different sequences.

I currently have code that does this serially. It searches each entry in the list for one sequence, then searches the list for the next sequence, then the next, and so on.

As an example of what I how I would structure the code, I was thinking something like the following:

```
library(Biostrings)
library(parallel)

#The data
sequences <- c("ATGGTA","CGAACT","AAATGC","CTTTGA","ACCAGT")
biglist <- list("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATGGTACCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC",
                "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATGCTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT",
                "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACGAACTGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG",
                "TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCTTTGACCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC",
                "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGACCAGTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")

#Making clusters for parallel workload
cl1 <- makeCluster(detectCores()/2)
cl2 <- makeCluster(detectCores()/2)
clusterExport(cl1, c("sequences","biglist","length","nchar","matchPattern"))
clusterExport(cl2, c("sequences","biglist","length","nchar","matchPattern"))

#Converting biglist to nucleotide sequence for matchPattern to read
biglistDNA <- parLapply(cl1,
                        1:length(biglist),
                        function(i) DNAString(biglist[[i]],
                                              start = 1,
                                              nchar = nchar(biglist[[i]])
                                             )
                       )

#Exporting the new list
clusterExport(cl1, "biglistDNA")
clusterExport(cl2, "biglistDNA")

#The problem child
Matched <- parLapply(c(cl1,cl2),
                     1:length(sequences),
                     function (i) {parLapply(
                                             cl1,
                                             1:length(biglistDNA),
                                             function(j){length(
                                                         nchar(
                                                         matchPattern(
                                                         sequences[i],
                                                         biglistDNA[[j]],
                                                         0,
                                                         0
                                                         )
                                                         )
                                                         )
                                                        }
                                            )
                                  }
                    )
```

What I would expect (and want) is a list where the first element is a list stating how many matches were found between the first element of sequences and each element of biglistDNA, the second element would be a list stating how many matches were found between the second element of sequences and each element of biglistDNA, and so on, and so forth. I know that length of nchar of matchPattern gives me the amount of matches between a query sequence and a subject sequence from running my code serially.

Something like this

```
Matched
[[1]]
[1] 1 0 0 0 0
[[2]]
[1] 0 0 1 0 0
[[3]]
[1] 0 1 0 0 0
[[4]]
[1] 0 0 0 1 0
[[5]]
[1] 0 0 0 0 1
```

When I run the code, I get 
`Error in checkCluster(cl) : not a valid cluster`.

I am guessing this means I cannot use multiple clusters the way I intended for parLapply. It is the same error I get if I try to use `clusterExport` with a vector of cluster objects. Is there a way of incrementing those indices individually? The elements of the list I want to generate are not dependent on each other, so there should be a way to do them in parallel.

Comment: (1) I think `cl` is not a variable you can pass to nodes within the cluster (I may be wrong). (2) Doing nested `parLapply` seems not right to me (I'm not saying it isn't, but I wouldn't have though to do it). I'd suggest either (a) accept simple `lapply` on the inner loop, or (b) use `expand.grid` to generate all (necessary) combinations of `biglist` and `sequences` in the main loop, and then go parallel with each row of this expanded frame.

Comment: Several "BTW"'s with this code: (1) `biglist` is a `list`, so shouldn't it be `biglist[[i]]`? (2) as opposed to `1:length(...)`, I recommend either `seq_along(...)` or `seq_len(length(...))`, it'll defend against incorrect indexing on a 0-length vector/list. (3) Is there a reason you're applying against `1:length(...)` instead of the data itself, as in `parLapply(cl, biglist, function(x) ...)`? If you don't need the index number, why not just pass the value itself?

Comment: You are right on (1). This isn't a copy and paste of my actual code. That is just a typo. (2) I know the data I am working with won't give me 0-length vector/list. The only way it would happen in the case I am using is if I had no DNA reads from sequencing. As for (3) this was just how I was taught to use lapply/parLapply. I have seen other people using lapply where they feed the data like you suggested, but I could never get the syntax right. Call it a bad habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data

```
sequences <- c("ATGGTA","CGAACT","AAATGC","CTTTGA","ACCAGT")
biglist <- list("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATGGTACCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC",
            "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATGCTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT",
            "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACGAACTGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG",
            "TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCTTTGACCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC",
            "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGACCAGTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
```

As @r2evans points out in the comments, it doesn't make sense to declare 2 clusters. You'll be using all of the available cores whether you declare 1 or N clusters.

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)
```

You technically only need to export `biglist` to the cluster since the elements of `sequences` will be passed through `parLapply`

```
clusterExport(cl, c("biglist"))
```

The following `parLapply` statement will iterate through `sequences`, passing each element to a new core. Within a core, it will execute the `function(x) { ... }`. In this case, you can achieve the result you're after with the vectorized (note: fast) `grepl(pattern, list)`. `grepl` will search the list of strings for the presence of the pattern.

```
parLapply(cl, sequences, function(x) { grepl(x, biglist) + 0 })
```

Output

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 0 0 0 0

[[2]]
[1] 0 0 1 0 0

[[3]]
[1] 0 1 0 0 0

[[4]]
[1] 0 0 0 1 0

[[5]]
[1] 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: If I may ask, is the + 0 there to convert TRUE to a numeric value of 1? If so, doing it this way, I lose the information on how many matches actually exist between the query and subject. Also, I am sorry, but I am not familiar with grepl. Would I have to input each possible acceptable mutation into the object `sequences` if I wanted to allow for mutations in the sequences I listed there? Another reason I use matchPatterns is that it allows me to specify the max amount of mismatches I allow between the query and subject (or in this case pattern and string from a list).

Comment: Yes, `+ 0` is to convert logical to numeric. Yes, if you wanted to stick with `grepl`, you would have to add each mutation into `sequences`. If you want to accept mutations, I suggest sticking with `matchPatterns`.

Comment: Do not nest `parLapply`. You have to decide which `lapply` statement you want to parallelize. In this case, I would parallelize the outer `lapply` (across sequences) and keep the inner `lapply` (across 1:length of biglist) a normal `lapply`.

Comment: If I had `lapply` on `sequences` and `parLapply` on `1:length(biglist)`, would that act like having a series of `parLapply`s, where each `parLapply` takes an element of vector `sequence`? My code in RStudio is currently that series, which I seek to parallelize, since it is still too slow for my biglist files that contain 100mil+ sequences, and also because the output each of `parLapply` is independent from the others. If I use `parLapply` on sequences and `lapply` across `biglist`, would that really be faster (seeing as how `biglist` is millions of sequences, and `sequences` is only 5)?

Comment: You're right, you want to parallelize `1:length(biglist)`. My only concern is that passing data between cores can oftentimes lead to a slowdown. If you parallelize `biglist`, you are passing 100mil data objects and recollecting 100mil results. This is why I suggest finding a vectorized solution to your problem rather than simply a parallelization solution

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. I think I can suck it up, and type out 120 different search sequences (4 possibilities per nucleotide position, 6 nucleotide length, 5 sequences, 1 mutation per sequence) if vectorizing with `grepl` will really be fast. Or I can look for a way to generate those mutations.